# GIT: Can't stage changes to commit, Can't pull until I commit the changes

Tags: git, github, push, commit, pull

I get this with git status:

```
git status
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 3 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
    (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
Changes not staged for commit:
    (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
    (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   application/models/Usuario_model.php
    modified:   application/views/Autor/listar.php
    modified:   application/views/Libro/modificar.php
    modified:   application/views/Libro/perfil.php
    modified:   application/views/ListaLibros/listar.php
    modified:   application/views/Valoracion/crearOk.php

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

`git add <file>` does nothing

`git pull` produces this:

```
git pull
: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    application/models/Usuario_model.php
    application/views/Autor/listar.php
    application/views/Libro/perfil.php
    application/views/ListaLibros/listar.php
    application/views/Valoracion/crearOk.php
commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
```

I can't push because "the tip of my current branch is behind its remote counterpart".

So I can't push before pulling, I can't pull before committing and I can't commit because I can't stage the changes.

What is going on and how can I fix It?

Comment: You can try `git add *` before executing `git commit -m "Your Message"`.

Comment: What happens when you run `git add application` and then `git status`? What is the output after both of these commands?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Nothing happens after `git add application` and `git status` shows everything as it was before

Comment: that is very strange. Check your `.gitignore` file to see if any of the rules match those files. Make sure you are in the correct directory. Finally, if all else fails, you can use `git stash` as described in my answer to allow you to pull the changes. Unfortunately, you will still have to address the problem with committing your changes anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If those files are going to be committed for the first time, you can try

`git add *` or `git add .`

Next you can commit your changes by,

`git commit -m "Your Message"`

(If the files were previously committed, you can combine the above two commands in one command to stage them as, `git commit -a -m "Your Message"`)

Later, you can pull using

`git pull <remote_name> <branch_name>` .

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

In this case it sounds like you want to make a commit but for some reason you are unable to. If you are okay with forgoing the commit until later, you can run `git stash` to temporarily commit your changes to the "stash". This also cleans your local copy. After doing `git pull` and resolving any merge conflicts, you can do `git stash apply` to apply the stashed changes to your local copy or `git stash pop` to also remove the changes from the stash.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify what you are adding with `git add`. Either use `git add --all` or specify exact files e.q. `git add application/models/Usuario_model.php` (wildcards are supported).

Or you can do stage + commit simultaneously with `git commit -a`.

See [git add](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) and [git commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit).

Comment: I tried git add -A and specifying file like "git add application/models/Usuario_model.php" but it didn't work.  I tried git add --all and it worked!!. Isn't that the same as git add -A?

Comment: @JuanAntonioRodríguezGabriel I think they are the same. What was the error you get on 'git add -A' ?

Comment: No error at all. The console just showed and empty prompt after pressing enter